# Problemas con el mensaje de error en autenticación de adminlte3

Tags: php, laravel, adminlte

estoy utilizando admiltle3 en un sistema hecho con laravel 9 y tengo un problema a la hora del login; si no pongo nada en la contraseña si me trae el error de que está vacío, pero si escribo la contraseña incorrecta, no me trae ningún error de regreso.
De la misma manera, el @csrf no está funcionando (error 419) aunque está en el código, pero solo en el login.

No coloco ningún código porque realmente no sé dónde buscar.

Intenté lo mencionado en [este link](https://github.com/jeroennoten/Laravel-AdminLTE/issues/972) pero es una versión más vieja de la que tengo actualmente, que es:

```
"jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^3.9"
```

Mi login.blade.php no tiene casi cambios:

```
@extends('adminlte::auth.auth-page', ['auth_type' => 'login'])

@section('adminlte_css_pre')
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('vendor/icheck-bootstrap/icheck-bootstrap.min.css') }}">
@stop

@php( $login_url = View::getSection('login_url') ?? config('adminlte.login_url', 'login') )
@php( $register_url = View::getSection('register_url') ?? config('adminlte.register_url', 'register') )
@php( $password_reset_url = View::getSection('password_reset_url') ?? config('adminlte.password_reset_url', 'password/reset') )

@if (config('adminlte.use_route_url', false))
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? route($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? route($register_url) : '' )
    @php( $password_reset_url = $password_reset_url ? route($password_reset_url) : '' )
@else
    @php( $login_url = $login_url ? url($login_url) : '' )
    @php( $register_url = $register_url ? url($register_url) : '' )
    @php( $password_reset_url = $password_reset_url ? url($password_reset_url) : '' )
@endif

@section('auth_header', __('adminlte::adminlte.login_message'))

@section('auth_body')
    <form action="{{ $login_url }}" method="post">
        @csrf

        {{-- Email field --}}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" id="login" name="login" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror"
                   value="{{ old('name') }}" placeholder="Usuario" autofocus>

            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="fas fa-envelope {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_icon', '') }}"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            @error('email')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>

        {{-- Password field --}}
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror"
                   placeholder="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.password') }}">

            <div class="input-group-append">
                <div class="input-group-text">
                    <span class="fas fa-lock {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_icon', '') }}"></span>
                </div>
            </div>

            @error('password')
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                </span>
            @enderror
        </div>

        {{-- Login field --}}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-7">
                <div class="icheck-primary" title="{{ __('adminlte::adminlte.remember_me_hint') }}">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" id="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}>

                    <label for="remember">
                        {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.remember_me') }}
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col-5">
                <button type=submit class="btn btn-block {{ config('adminlte.classes_auth_btn', 'btn-flat btn-primary') }}">
                    <span class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></span>
                    {{ __('adminlte::adminlte.sign_in') }}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    </form>
@stop
```